# Macbook monitor is black but not broken, likely other issues

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I'm having issues with my screen, which is black. It works though but usually only when I boot it up. I'm fairly certain there's other issues which is causing this issue.

For example I am unable to boot into safe mode and I am unable to switch to windows when it boots up. I have tried all the things suggested, like resetting nram och pram, smc and whatever more I have found but it doesn't seem to work. I have just updated to the Monterey but that didn't help either.

What could possibly be wrong and how do I fix it? It's a Macbook pro 2016.

Thanks!

Comment: Does an external monitor work?

Comment: Yes it works with an external monitor

Comment: What do you mean "it works but usually only when I boot it up". Does it stop working at some point after booting? Not Booting into Safe Mode doesn't sound good: this is likely to be something that needs to be physically assessed by a trained person, e.g. at an Apple Store or other Mac shop.